# similarity score is way off using doc2vec embedding

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding, doc2vec

I'm trying out document de-duplication on an *NY-Times* corpus that I've prepared very recently. It contains data related to financial fraud.

First, I convert the article snippets to a list of `TaggedDocument` objects.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def create_tagged_doc(doc, nlp):        
    toks = nlp(doc)
    lemmatized_toks = [tok.lemma_ for tok in toks if not tok.is_stop]
    return lemmatized_toks

df_fraud = pd.read_csv('...local_path...')
df_fraud_list = df_fraud['snippet'].to_list()
documents = [TaggedDocument(create_tagged_doc(doc, nlp), [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(df_fraud_list)]
```

A sample `TaggedDocument` looks as follows:

```
TaggedDocument(words=['Chicago', 'woman', 'fall', 'mortgage', 'payment', 
'victim', 'common', 'fraud', 'know', 'equity', 'strip', '.'], tags=[1])
```

Now I compile and train the Doc2Vec model.

```
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
model_dbow = Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=100, negative=5, hs=0, min_count=2, sample = 0, workers=cores)
model_dbow.build_vocab(documents)
model_dbow.train(documents, 
                total_examples=model_dbow.corpus_count, 
                epochs=model_dbow.epochs)
```

Let's define the cosine similarity:

```
cosine_sim = lambda x, y: np.inner(x, y) / (norm(x) * norm(y))
```

Now, the trouble is, if I define two sentences which are almost similar and take their cosine similarity score, it's coming very low. E.g.

```
a = model_dbow.infer_vector(create_tagged_doc('That was a fradulent transaction.', nlp))
b = model_dbow.infer_vector(create_tagged_doc('That transaction was fradulant.', nlp))

print(cosine_sim(a, b)) # 0.07102317
```

Just to make sure, I checked with exact same vector repeated, and it's proper.

```
a = model_dbow.infer_vector(create_tagged_doc('That was a fradulent transaction.', nlp))
b = model_dbow.infer_vector(create_tagged_doc('That was a fradulent transaction.', nlp))

print(cosine_sim(a, b)) # 0.9980062
```

What's going wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's an issue with number of epochs. When creating a Doc2Vec instance without specifying number of epochs, e.g. `model_dbow = Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=100, negative=5, hs=0, min_count=2, sample = 0, workers=cores)`, it's set to 5 by default. Apparently that wasn't sufficient for my corpus. I set the epochs to 50, and re-trained the model, and voila! It worked.

Comment: Aha! Yes, that's an easier/nicer boost than the analysis in my answer considered – which I've posted anyway in case it's helpful in other ways. Yes, the default `epochs` for `Doc2Vec` should be higher than the value 5 inherited from `Word2Vec`. A lot of published work uses 10-20, though especially for smaller corpuses or smaller texts, even larger may help. Also, it can sometimes be helpful to use an even-larger `epochs` on `.infer_vector()` – especially for very-short texts. (By default it will reuse the `epochs` remembered from instance-creation.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the actual tokens you're passing to `infer_vector()`:

```
In [4]: create_tagged_doc('That was a fradulent transaction.', nlp)                                                           
Out[4]: ['fradulent', 'transaction', '.']

In [5]: create_tagged_doc('That transaction was fradulant.', nlp)                                                             
Out[5]: ['transaction', 'fradulant', '.']
```

The misspelling `'fraudulant'` is probably not in your NYT corpus, and thus may be unknown to the `Doc2Vec` model, and thus ignored. So you're really calculating doc-vectors for:

`['fradulent', 'transaction', '.']` vs `['transaction', '.']`

Further, `'.'` probably isn't very significant - especially if it was present in *all* training examples. And note that tiny examples (of one to a few words) don't have many subtly-contrasting influences to balance - they're stark utterances, perhaps unlike the bulk of the training data, and inference will be relatively short & with minimal counterbalancing influences (compared to longer texts).

For example, in a `Doc2Vec` model where words and vectors are co-trained and comparable, like PV-DM models (`dm=1`), I'm not sure whether for a single-word document like `['transaction']`, the more-useful vector would be the inference on that token-list, or just the word-vector for `'transaction'`.

And finally, since the range for similarity is `-1.0` to `1.0`, `0.07` maybe isn't *that* bad for an effective comparison between `['fradulent', 'transaction', '.']` and `['transaction', '.']`.

Comment: The misspelling totally slipped through my eyes, thanks for pointing that out.